# Change Blogspot RSS Feed Thumbnail Size (now 72px) to max resolution

Tags: image, rss, blogger

I would like to change Blogspot Rss Feed Thumbnail size (default is 72px) to max image resolution because images are pixeled when feed are shown.

How can i do that?

Where i put this code?

```
imagePath.replace(/s72-c/, 's0');
```

Thxs

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Simply replace size flag in image path you get from object:

```js
imagePath.replace(/s72-c/, 's0');
```

Comment: please update your question with a snippet code so we can help you.